# Different Ways to Make Edges (look) Sharp

Tags: edges

This is such a newbie question and I have failed to fully understand the differences between these functions as they all seem to have a similar effect. Could someone please better elaborate?

-Mark Sharp

-Mean Crease

-Edge Loops after SubD Modifier

and

-Edge Split Modifier

-Auto Smooth (Why even smooth if it just makes it flat again)

I've seen these used in different situations and don't fully understand why that technique was chosen over another.

Thank you!

Comment: This will answer a few of them. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBkwodrQq_4

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odnMxHGlj1s

Comment: I personally stay away from all these solutions except edge loops (and bevels, which are edge loops) but it doesn't really answer your question and some will disapprove

Comment: Love Autosmooth. Working on HDMI connector ports. Need the top and bottom to be Flat shaded and the sides to be Smooth shaded. Only where the angle increases above the limit (default 30) does the Smoothing apply to those faces. Avoids having to add a huge amount of geometry to get a smooth curve.